# SQL Slow Inserting

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server

I have an ASP.NET application that takes a bunch of datasets that are stored in XML and expands them out into SQL, in the expand process it carrys out a large number of inserts.

These inserts are taking quite some time, now I'll openly admit that my SQL skills are not that great, so my diagnostic methods may seem a little crude.

On the SQL Server Management Activity Monitor the processor time sits around 3%, the actual CPU usage on the server is around that as well, so the code is not running flat out, there are 0 waiting tasks, and the I/O is steady at 0.3MB/Sec, batch requests are at around 180/sec

In resource waits the Logging has a wait time of around 900ms, which lead me in the direction of slow disks, I moved the log files to a different set of spindles and that increased my batch requests to 260/sec but it certainly wasn't going flat out.

Am I right in thinking that its the disks that are causing the slowness on this box and everything is essentially waiting patiently for its turn on the disks, aside from new server (Its an old HP DL385 Dual CPU with UW320 Disks) is there a way to speed up inserts?

Comment: Are you inserting rows one at a time?

Comment: Yes, the rows are extracted from the datasets and slightly modified to insert the ID of the table that they are linked to before they are inserted. I have run a generate scripts  (Schema and Data) and then run that to insert the data back in and that takes the same amount of time give or take a few seconds.

Comment: You might want to consider using SSIS with an XML source and SQL destination.

Comment: We talking stored procedures? as in feed in a few variables then run the expand from there (the whole expand process is essentially SQL, and C# code could be ported over to SQL)

Comment: Is non-blocking inserts an option in your application?

Comment: Things to verify in the client (the Asp.Net app): Are you creating a new Sql connection and a new command for each insert? If possible reuse connection and commands. Are you insertin data in increasing clustered index order? If not, can that be changed? Things to look for in Sql server: Are you inserting to heavily indexed tables? What's the fill factor on the indices? Are there triggers on the tables you are inserting to? Are there user function constraints on some data in these tables? Lot's of questions, but not knowing more details it's difficult to say anything specific...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For mass inserts to SQL Server, you should really be using `SqlBulkCopy` for your requirements.

Here is a small example.

```
// Set up your target fields and types
Dictionary<string, string> uploadFields = new Dictionary<string, string>()
{
    { "LocationId", "System.Int32" },
    { "CalendarDate", "System.DateTime" },
    { "IsWorkingDay", "System.Boolean" },
    { "SnapshotDate", "System.DateTime" }
};

// Set up a DataTable to hold the stuff we want to send.
DataTable   massUpdate  = new DataTable();

// Use the dictionary above to set up columns
uploadFields
  .Keys
  .ToList()
  .ForEach(k => massUpdate.Columns.Add(k, Type.GetType(uploadFields[k])));

// Populate your datatable
foreach ( var thing in things )
{

   DataRow row = massUpdate.NewRow();

   row["LocationId"]       = thing.Id;
   row["CalendarDate"]     = thing.Date;
   row["IsWorkingDay"]     = thing.IsWorkingDay;
   row["SnapshotDate"]     = DateTime.UtcNow;

   massUpdate.Rows.Add(row);
}

// Finally, send the contents of the DataTable up via SqlBulkCopy.
// GetConnectionString
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Your connection string"))
{
  using (SqlBulkCopy copy = new SqlBulkCopy(conn))
  {
    conn.Open();

    foreach (var key in uploadFields.Keys)
    {
      copy.ColumnMappings.Add(key, key);
    }

    // Swap this table name with yoyr own.
    copy.DestinationTableName = "DestinationTableName";
    copy.WriteToServer(massUpdate);
    conn.Close();
  }
}
```

Docs:-

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Not totally familiar with the environment you're in, but are transactions possible? If so, you can speed up your INSERTs drastically by first starting a transaction, then doing a bunch of INSERTs, then ending the transaction. Otherwise, every INSERT is running as its own transaction and therefore has a lot of processing around it just to get it done.

Comment: If thats how the output from a 'Generate Script' does it then that no faster, both cases take around 9 minutes to insert 79949 rows into the database.